# Cygwin doesn't define __STDC_IEC_559__

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, newlib

I was curious if this is intentional. I found that traditionally `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined in glibc and then used by gcc. Cygwin doesn't use glibc however, and I was wondering if `__STDC_IEC_559__` isn't defined by newlib for whatever reason or if it is merely a problem on my end.

I understand that all compilers/libraries do not define `__STDC_IEC_559__` as they are not all compliant with the standard, I am just trying to figure out why the libraries used by cygwin specifically are not.

Comment: One thing to note is that, while the presence of `__STDC_IEC_559__` requires compliance, it's absence does not *necessarily* indicate a lack of compliance.

Comment: The newlib docs do not seem to discuss the matter.  However, in view of the wide variety of hardware toward which newlib is targeted (much wider than Glibc), I speculate that the maintainers are simply unprepared to guarantee full conformance with C17 G.2 - G.7 on all supported platforms, nor to devote effort to figuring out on which platforms, if any, newlib does fully conform.  Are there specific features or behaviors that you want to rely upon?

Comment: I was specifically attempting to make sure float was complying with the standard. I could not really find any other way to simply do this besides relying on that macro.